# Use text editing controller inside on changed flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to use my text editing controller userNameController.text as a string value to pass into onChanged(). When the text field has something in it, I have a Boolean isUserFilled which is set to true, and false when the text field is empty, I originally was using the system keyboard and this worked just fine. Although I am now using a keyboard which is connected to a text editing controller and the Boolean is no longer changing. I am also getting this error:

The prefix 'userNameController' can't be used here because it is shadowed by a local declaration, Try renaming either the prefix or the local declaration.

How can I grab the text from the text editing controller and pass it into the onchanged() so that when the text field has a value, it changes the Boolean true?

I attached the code below which has the text editing controller connected to controller:

textfield for username

```
TextField(
                      // Checking the UserName textField for user input, returns a boolean to isUserFilled
                     controller: userNameController,
                      readOnly: true,
                      showCursor: true,
                      onTap: () {
                       setState(() {
                         keyboardUp ? _controller.reverse() : _controller.forward();
                         userSelected = true;
                       });
                      },
                      onChanged: (userNameController.text) {
                        setState(() {
                          isUserFilled = userNameController.text.isNotEmpty;
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
```

textfield for password

```
TextField(
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                     controller: passwordController,
                      readOnly: true,
                      showCursor: true,
                      obscureText: true,
                      onTap: () {
                        userSelected = false;
                        keyboardUp = false;
                      },
                      // Checking the Password textField for user input, returns a boolean to isPasswordFilled
                      onChanged: (input) {
                        setState(() {
                          isPasswordFilled = passwordController.text.isNotEmpty;
                          print(isPasswordFilled);
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
```

methods which change the color upon conditional

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

bool isUserFilled = true; // I think these may be the issue
bool isPasswordFilled = true;

Color backgroundColor()
{

  // This function uses the boolean value isUserFilled
  // to decide which color to use as background in the login button
  if (isUserFilled == false && isPasswordFilled == false)  {
    return Color.fromRGBO(156, 156, 156, 50);
  } else if (isUserFilled == true && isPasswordFilled == true){
    return Color.fromRGBO(70, 224, 64, 1);
  } else {
    return Color.fromRGBO(156, 156, 156, 50);
  }
}

String iconColor()
{
  // This function uses the boolean value isUserFilled
  // to decide which image to use in the login button
  if (isUserFilled == false && isPasswordFilled == false) {
    return 'assets/login/run_protocol_grey.png';
  } else if (isUserFilled == true && isPasswordFilled == true) {
    return 'assets/login/run_protocol_white.png';
  } else {
    return 'assets/login/run_protocol_grey.png';
  }
}

Color textColor()
{
  // This function uses the boolean value isUserFilled
  // to decide which color the text will be in the login button
  if (isUserFilled == false && isPasswordFilled == false) {
    return Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1);
  } else if (isUserFilled == true && isPasswordFilled == true) {
    return Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1);
  } else {
    return Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@override
void initState(){
 userNameController.addListener(() {
   setState(() {
     isUserFilled = userNameController.text.isNotEmpty
   });
  });
}
```

Comment: This is what I had for the original code, but unfortunately it grabs the text from the system keyboard. It is not grabbing the text from the text editing controller.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're adding extra values. I made edit, please check it.

Comment: It seems to just keep returning false, I added a print statement print(isUserFilled), and even with input in the text field it is just returning false.

Comment: That is weird, can you post your entire code?

Comment: This is a big application, but I can post the code for the functions I am using to change the values when the conditional changes, this might be where my problem is, because I do not think it is updating the Boolean, but it works fine if I hard code the values for isUserFilled and isPasswordFilled. I will add this code.

Comment: Working with `v.isNotEmpty` should even work, can you try that please?

Comment: For password you have `input` so try `input.isNotEmpty`

Comment: This seemed to do the trick, thank you very much, It seems that the listener can see input from the text editing controller the same way that the input in onChanged is able to see input from the system keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the value from the controller to `onChanged` (in fact, it's not possible, because the value passed to the `onChanged` function is passed in by the TextField widget itself).

Whatever value is in the textfield after the field is changed, that is what is passed into `onChanged`.

Therefore, you can simply do this (for each of your fields):

```
// Username
onChanged: (newValue) {
  setState(() {
    isUserFilled = !newValue.isEmpty;
  });
},

// Password
onChanged: (newValue) {
  setState(() {
    isPasswordFilled = !newValue.isEmpty;
  });
},
```